# how can I make google +1 button hover message be transparent

Tags: css, google-plus

How can I edit the styling of these part of google +1 button? *kinda hard for me to explain the detail in english. so I make this picture*
[image]

I know it's located inside an iframe, some says that we couldn't edit the styles inside an iframe which sourced from other domain. but apparently, I have successfully styled my facebook like button to be looking good (transparent on the border). And also, I saw some other sites which have a nice looking google +1 button (without those blocking solid white background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: possible solution:**

Looking at the markup and css on the page below it looks like somewhere in your css you must be setting the `background-color` of the `div` that the bubble is contained in to `white` or `#fff`. Try something like:-

```
.pls-container {background-color:transparent}
```

Do you have a link to this page, or a site that has a +1 button which has the same rollover so people can experiment? It would be easier to give a definite solution then...

**Edit:** just had a look [here](http://kikolani.com/you-guide-to-the-google-1-button.html) at the +1 buttons (at the top of the post and in the sidebar at the right) these both appear to be transparent borders - so there must be something different about your page. You could try looking at that page as an example and see where you've gone wrong, but without the code to your page it will be very difficult to give a solution to your problem directly.